# Human capital for under developed countries

Tags: economic-growth, human-capital

I am currently undergoing a study on economic growth in 11 countries: Bangladesh, Egypt, Indonesia, Iran, Mexico, Philippines, Pakistan, South Korea, Turkey and Vietnam. I plan to use panel regression. I plan to follow an analysis such as Islam (1995) and Barro (1991) with an augmented Solow model with human capital.

As my human capital variable I am using the "Index of human capital per person" (based on years of schooling and returns to education), from the Penn-world tables. My question is, how would I go about finding the savings ratio $S_h$ i.e. the investment in human capital from the above index?

Answer (score 3):

If you multiply the index by the population size (or the quantity used to compute the *per person* index), you get an index of the **stock of human capital.** For example, if for a given country the index is $h_t$ and population is $N_t$, then the stock is:

$$ H_t = h_t \times N_t $$

Now, by the definition a stock follows an accumulation rule, just as physical capital:

$$ H_{t+1} = H_t(1+d_t) + I_t $$

where $d_t$ is the "depreciation" of HK (e.g. because of death or skill obsolescence) and $I_t$ is **gross** investment in HK. Since you probably do not have data on depreciation (which I imagine is very difficult to compute), you can only calculate **net** investment, which is equivalent to net savings by definition:

$$ S^h_t = H_{t+1} - H_t $$

Finally, to compute the savings **rate**, you need to divide this by a measure of GDP. **However, these need to be measured in the same units**. Therefore, you need to transform $H_t$ or $S^h_t$ into **monetary units**. For this you need something like the average price of human capital for every period, which I have never seen, and seems not available in Penn-world tables.

Comment: Why the downvote?